# Problem with ASP.NET drop downs in Internet Explorer 8 and zooming

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I’ve spotted a problem with ASP.NET drop downs in Internet Explorer 8 with zooming. Note: The problem doesn’t seem to occur in Firefox or Opera.

On a page that has drop downs, **if you zoom in (CTRL+) and then back out again (CTRL-), the height of the drop downs remains too tall** – they seem to remain at the height that they were when the page was zoomed in.

Is this a bug with Internet Explorer? Is there a work around?